# RewriteRule for SEO url's

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to use RewriteRule but can't seem to get the hang of it.

These are the layers of the website:

```
http://domain.com/artists/artist-name/1/2/3/
http://domain.com/fairytales/fairy-tale-one/1/2/3/
http://domain.com/horrorstories/horror-story-six/1/2/3/
```

Basically, it is the dir before the '/1/' in the url's that should be the cool SEO url name.

I understood so far, it should be something like this to rewrite propely.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/artists/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?artist_id=$1&cat_id=$2&style_id=$3
RewriteRule ^/fairytales/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?story_id=$1&cat_id=$2&style_id=$3
RewriteRule ^/horrorstories/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?story_id=$1&cat_id=$2&style_id=$3
```

.htaccess works with Apache 2.4.23 on the CentOS server i am using.

After the many 500 errors and now too many 404's, I'm finally asking.

Comment: Just use a routing library, there are many to choose from, and they will all be more feature rich and robust than your own diy version: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20router

Comment: I know! The thing is that i can't get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex patterns are not matching given URLs. Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?artists/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?artist_id=$1&cat_id=$2&style_id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^/?fairytales/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?story_id=$1&cat_id=$2&style_id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^/?horrorstories/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?story_id=$1&cat_id=$2&style_id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I think you just made my year @anubhava! Let me test some more here.

Comment: This is too great! You made it work! Can I also ask how this should be done with say more variables? Or infinite variables perhaps maybe?

Comment: Sorry there is no infinite variable magic solution. For very complicated case consider using [Front Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) but for adding 1 or 2 new variables can be worked out using rewrite rules like above.